# Eliminating duplicate values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
select distinct
    FA_ADD.ASSET_ID,
    FA_ADD.ASSET_NUMBER,
    PPA.SEGMENT1
from 
    apps.FA_ADDITIONS FA_ADD
left join
    apps.FA_ASSET_INVOICES FAI on FAI.ASSET_ID = Fa_Add.ASSET_NUMBER
left join
    apps.PA_PROJECTS_ALL PPA on PPA.PROJECT_ID = FAI.PROJECT_ID
where 
    FA_ADD.ASSET_NUMBER in ('110011427', '110011425', '100004472', '110011480','100004641')
order by 
    FA_ADD.ASSET_ID;
```

Please help me with this query.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71yoN.png)

In the example output above, I need the rows 1, 2, 3, 5, 7

Comment: Pls do not use image! Write out your query, sample data and expected result

Comment: If you post your query as text I can show you how to do what you need. Move the join to `PPA` into a column as a subselect

Comment: I suppose you miss some condition on join to table PA_PROJECTS_ALL, because result contains null value on segment column from this table in results

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text (i.e. no links, no images.)

Comment: `group by` first two columns and then get `max()` of the third.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add conditions in the left outer join PA_PROJECTS_ALL to be more precise and not have duplicate lines.

try something like this

```
select distinct
    FA_ADD.ASSET_ID,
    FA_ADD.ASSET_NUMBER,
    PPA.SEGMENT1,
    fa_add.DESCRIPTION
    from apps.FA_ADDITIONS FA_ADD
    LEFT JOIN apps.FA_ASSET_INVOICES FAI on FAI.ASSET_ID = Fa_Add.ASSET_NUMBER
    LEFT JOIN apps.PA_PROJECTS_ALL PPA ON PPA.PROJECT_ID = FAI.PROJECT_ID and proj_num is not null
    where FA_ADD.ASSET_NUMBER in ('110011427','110011425','100004472','110011480')
    order by FA_ADD.ASSET_ID
```